# Data from Excel workbook to a chart with ASP

Tags: asp.net, excel, charts

is there a way to create a chart for a website with asp.net? The workbook would be updated sometimes so it needs to update itself on a website. If yes, will I be able to add this file to my other HTML, css and JavaScript files?
If it is possible I would be grateful for providing a sample code.

Comment: This is possible. You could read the data from the workbook on every request (or cache it) and send the data in your request as an array. You can use a javascript library to use the data for rendering a chart.

Comment: Could you introduce me further into this? I've been trying to show my chart on website since thursday and Im confused now

Comment: Take a look at http://www.chartjs.org .

Comment: Thank you kindly, but still I can't find any example with linking the excel workbook and read data from it directly

Comment: Look at these examples: https://forums.asp.net/t/1719856.aspx?Three+Methods+to+Read+Excel+with+ASP+NET

Comment: Is it possible to do this if im not using the asp.net?

Comment: Im writing in html, css, javadcript in phpstorm

Comment: I have no knowledge of php

Comment: Well I just use PHPStorm to write code. I have no php files in my website. Im trying to get the charts with use of html css and js only.

Comment: Do you use node.js server side?

Comment: Im not familiar with that but if this helps in any way then yes, I have it installed on the computer